# Capturing NOTE generated by _ERROR_ condition from input statement

Tags: sas

Below is a simple representation of my problem.  I do not control the data, nor the format applied (this is a backend service for a Stored Process Web App).  My goal is to return the error message generated - which in this case is actually a `NOTE`.

```
data _null_;
input x 8.;
cards;
4 4
;
run;
```

The above generates:

> NOTE: Invalid data for x in line 61 1-8.  RULE:
>   ----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8----+----9----+----0                       61         4 4  x=. *ERROR*=1 *N*=1  NOTE: DATA statement used (Total
>   process time):
>          real time           0.00 seconds
>          cpu time            0.01 seconds

It's easy enough to capture the error status (`if _error_ ne 0 then do`) but what I'd like to do is return the value of the NOTE - which handily tells us which column was invalid, along with line and column numbers.

Is this possible without log scanning?  I've tried `sysmsg()` and `syswarningtext` to no avail.

Comment: I had a little hope that the undocumented system option dsoptions=note2err might help by turning that NOTE: into an ERROR: , so you could use &syserrortext.  But sadly, it's still a NOTE even with note2err turned on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, There is no feature for capturing the NOTES a data step causes while the data step is running.

Since you are in STP environment, you might either use either:

- `-altlog` at session startup or
- `proc printto log=…` wrap of the step

and do that scan.

Comment: I figured that must be the case.  Next challenge - how to find out where the log is currently being redirected!

Comment: found - thanks to Q (SAS-L), the current log location (if redirected) is in the `SYSPRINTTOLOG` system option.